# redirect to localized route after login in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, routes, fortify, laravel-jetstream

I am using localized routes in `laravel 8` application everything works fine, how can I change the redirect HOME variable in `RouteServiceProvider:20` to include the route `{locale}` parameter in HOME variable?

Currently it redirects to `http://localhost/dashboard` after successfully login, I want it to redirect to whatever the locale parameter is: for example `http://localhost/ar/dashboard`

```
web routes:

Route::prefix('{locale}')->group(function ($locale) {
    Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('/dashboard', function (Request $request) {
            return view('dashboard');
        })->name('dashboard');
    });

    require_once __DIR__ . "/fortify.php";

    require_once __DIR__ . "/jetstream.php";
});
```

```
RouteServiceProvider:
'
'
'
public const HOME = '/dashboard';
'
'
```

Comment: You can check out this article that probably solves your problem: https://laraveldaily.com/multi-language-routes-and-locales-with-auth/

Answer (score 0):

I made the next to fix this issue:

Find this line of code in the different controllers of auth folder:

```
RouteServiceProvider::HOME
```

And replace with this:

```
route('dashboard')
```

You have to check if the first line is inside of `intended()` here is an example:

```
return redirect()->intended(route('dashboard'));
```

In my web.php I have the next line:

```
Route::get(LaravelLocalization::transRoute('routes.dashboard'), [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->middleware(['auth','verified'])->name('dashboard');
```